# Avoid Angular.js orderBy default sorting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I'm new to Angular and I'm still trying to get my head around what's possible, so this may be a question with an obvious answer, but I can't find any relevant answers online.

I have a `switch statement` that decides which value to return to `orderBy`, and `orderBy` correctly ranks a list of objects according to the value returned. However, I want the `default` case of my `switch statement` to ensure that `orderBy` does nothing to the order of the list of objects.

However, it seems that `orderBy` has default functionality that orders the list its own way if you give it no value.

I've tried various ways to get it to work:

`default: return;` returns nothing and `orderBy` uses its default ordering.

`default:break;` returns nothing and `orderBy` uses its default ordering

`default: return [];` and `return ['']` I thought an empty array would be recognised as an argument, and would get around this, but it still uses the default ordering.

`default: return [':false'];` I thought passing some value in (reverse:false) would override the default ordering but I get an error for this.

I also set it up to use `orderBy: $index track by $index` - I thought it would just order it by the original index of the array. This didn't work.

> Does anyone know an argument I can pass into `orderBy` to get it to do
>   nothing at all to a list, or how I can override the default sorting.

Comment: you have to explicitly set your predicate to `null`.  all of the other scenarios you presented would either error or would trigger the default of `+`.

Comment: by not using orderBy is the answer - `ng-repeat="x in (wantToOrder ? (array | orderBy) : array)"`

Comment: @YOU that worked for me, thank you so much. if you want to turn your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @AnonyMouse, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not triggering orderBy is the only way for the time being.

E.g.

`ng-repeat="x in (wantToOrder ? (array | orderBy) : array)"`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up applying it like so: `data-ng-repeat-start="item in (getSortingCriteria() == null? items: (items | orderBy:getSortingCriteria()))`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the `orderBy` property value to `null`.

`propertyName = null` in JS

or

`ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:null"` in HTML

The docs don't mention this directly but there is an example that disables sorting by replacing the property string to a plain null.

```
<button ng-click="propertyName = null; reverse = false">Set to unsorted</button>
  <hr/>
  <table class="friends">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('name')">Name</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('phone')">Phone Number</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('age')">Age</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

[the example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your help! For some reason this doesn't work for me, but my code is laid out quite differently to the example in this answer.

Comment: that's why it's highly recommended to provide code examples with your questions. and angular version